# SQL Insert where Col1 AND Col2 is not found

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, sql-insert, not-exists

**EDIT** Rephrased the question, to clarify...

I need to find a way to search for all records where `Col2 <> 1` 
The value in `Col1` can be represented with other values in Col2. 
The result should only show if value in `Col1` never have had a `value =1 in Col2` as the record then are missing in the table.

The ID's in `Col1` are to be found as unique records in another table, so I can make a `join`or make something like `table1.Col1=table2.Col2`

In the end I need it to `INSERT` **missing records** in `table1`where there is no records with an ID in `Col1` `AND` `Col2=1`.

`Table2`

```
Col1|Col2|Col3|
---------------
|   1|....|....|
|   2|....|....|
|   3|....|....|
|   4|....|....|
```

`Table1`

```
|Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|
-------------------
|   1|   1|....|....|
|   1|   2|....|....|
|   1|   3|....|....|
|   2|   3|....|....|
|   2|   4|....|....|
|   2|   5|....|....|
|   3|   1|....|....|
|   3|   2|....|....|
|   4|   2|....|....|
|   4|   3|....|....|
|   4|   4|....|....|
```

In the above table my search should only show me, and it is those ID's there need to be inserted with a `1` in `Col2`

`Table1`

```
|   2|....|....|....|
|   4|....|....|....|
```

... and leave out since they already a record where `Col2=1`

`Table1`

```
|   1|....|....|....|
|   3|....|....|....|
```

... since Col1 has a matching value where one of them in Col2 = 1.
I hope it makes sense.

I need an example of a SELECT as well as an INSERT IF NOT EXIST

Before I can run an insert I need to be sure that the logic works, so I need a SELECT statement there can show me the `Col1` values of the missing records.

Thank you

Leif B.

MS-SQL Server 2016 with MSSMS 2019

Comment: I understand your stated logic, but it is not clear why you chose the output set you did, because there are other result sets which would also satisfy the requirement.  Please elaborate on this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I need to insert a record if Col1 and Col2 together doesn't exist

Comment: Your comment unfortunately does not help to explain your question.

Comment: You say: "where Col1 isn't represented with other values in the result". Col1 has values: 1, 2, 3, 4. Col2 only have those values, so why are there any records in the result-set? (Except for |   2|   5|....|....|). Any clarification you make should be edits to your Question. Kindly do not clarify your Question in comments.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I need to insert a record if Col1 and Col2 together doesn't exist

So in the above case it should insert a record where Col1=2 and Col1=4 only
However, I need to be sure that the logic works, so I need as well a SELECT statement there can show me the Col1 values there doesn't have a Col2=1 

If I just make a SELECT DISTINCT Col1 FROM Table WHERE Col2 <>1 I get all results shown, just not the records with Col2=1

Comment: @Scratte Sorry, I have edited question and hopefully clarified my question

Comment: Why is the example saying "Col1=2 and Col1= **4** only" but the insert is using `VALUES (2,1)`?

Comment: @Scratte It was just a fast example... I have corrected it...

Comment: Kindly try to slow down. `Col1=Col1` is always true (and there's no `FROM`) and now I'm getting confused about the `...,1`. I'm also confused why you want to insert a record of 2, 4 only. That seems to already exist. If you mean to say that you want all possible combinations of col1 and col2 in the table, then please state that. If you need a SQL to select all missing rows from that final resultset, please say that. If you do not want any addition to the resultset where col2 = 1, then please say that :)

Comment: @Scratte it is difficult for me to explain... 
I need a query to insert the missing ID in Col1 and set the value in Col2 to 1 in table1
All ID's (in Col1) are found unique in another table. Table1 is a connecting table missing some records

Comment: So.. you want to add only values (2,1) and (4,1) because col1 for both values 2 and 4 do not have a matching value 1 for col2? And you're only interested in adding rows with col2=1?

Comment: @Scratte `Col1=Col1` is always true depends on SQL dialect.  In Oracle this is only true if Col1 is not null.

Comment: @Taemyr Good catch. Missed that important `null` thing :(

Comment: @Scratte _So.. you want to add only values (2,1) and (4,1) because col1 for both values 2 and 4 do not have a matching value 1 for col2?_ Correct

_And you're only interested in adding rows with col2=1?_ I need the ID to be inserted as well, but else yes

I have rephrased my question, in a hope that it is more clear now...

Comment: One last thing: What's you RDBMS? Can you add a tag for it?

Comment: MS-SQL Server 2016 with MSSMS 2019 - I have updated the post with the sql-server-2008 tag, as I couldn't add sql-server-2016 tag

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still confusing.  You have a query that refers to two tables, but the sample data only shows one.

Based on your first paragraph, you can get the appropriate `col1` values as:

```
SELECT t1.col1, . . .
FROM t1
GROUP BY t1.col1
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN t1.col2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

The `. . .` is for additional columns.  You can then insert this into another table or the same table.  Perhaps:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (col1, col2, . . .)
    SELECT t1.col1, 0, . . .
    FROM t1
    GROUP BY t1.col1
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN t1.col2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Comment: For some reason I get an error because of the `GROUP BY`

Comment: @LeifB.  . . . Presumably the rest of the columns are not constants.  You need to use aggregation functions if you want other columns from `t1`.

Comment: It was in your `SELECT`where I only needed 1 column. So when I used ```SELECT t1.col1
FROM t1
GROUP BY t1.col1
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN t1.col2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;``` I got the error

Comment: @LeifB. . . . The syntax is fine:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5352c123252508494610f7fda7969e0b.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this solution...

```
/* *** The select query *** */
SELECT DISTINCT [Table1].[Col1]
FROM [Table1]
JOIN [Table2] ON [Table1].[Col1] = [Table2].[Col1]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT [Table1].[Col1], [Table1].[Col2] 
  FROM [Table1]
  WHERE [Table1].[Col1] = [Table2].[Col2] AND [Table1].[Col2] = 1)
```

```
/* *** The Insert query *** */
INSERT INTO [Table1]
([Table1].[Col1]
,[Table1].[Col2]
,[Table1].[Col3]
,[Table1].[Col4])
SELECT DISTINCT [Table1].[Col1]
,1
,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
,0
FROM [Table1]
JOIN [Table2] ON [Table1].[Col1] = [Table2].[Col1]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT [Table1].[Col1], [Table1].[Col2] 
FROM [Table1]
WHERE [Table1].[Col1] = [Table2].[Col2] AND [Table1].[Col2] = 1)
```